# Multiplication of tensor with batch data and a matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given a tensor `A` of shape `[?, n, m]` and a tensor `W` of shape `[m, m]`, I want to multiply each tensor `a` of shape `[n,m]`  of `A` with `W` resulting in a tensor of shape `[?, n, m]`.

I thought I could somehow do this with reshaping `W` to shape `[tf.shape(A)[0], n, m]`, but this does not result in a tensor of shape `[?, n, m]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed do that with reshaping:

```
tf.reshape(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(A, [-1, m]), W), [-1, n, m])
```